# passing an argument to add_action

Tags: wordpress

Given a function 'plugin_update' that would take a parameter $version, how can I pass a value to this method using the following syntax with the add_action method (as the method is within a class):

```
add_action('plugins_loaded',array('test-app-class','plugin_update'));
```

I have tried several variations that didn't seem to work. Any advice appreciated!

Comment: You can define `$version` as global variable and or add it as a const in your class. You shouldn't pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Try to avoid declaring globals. Why?  Globals are available to all of the code, meaning any code in the app can both read and write to it.  That means any code can change the value.  Why is that bad?  It makes the system less predictable as the state or value may not be expected.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Let me explain why.

### WordPress Event Engine Explanation

The `add_action` construct allows you to register a callback to an event.  In your case, the event is `plugins_loaded`.  The event is then fired when the construct `do_action()` or `do_action_ref_array`.

What happens when the event fires? WordPress Core does the following:

1. Assembles the arguments, if any are passed

   2. Sorts the event registry table
   3. Calls each of the registered callbacks in order (as determine by the priority number and when it loaded into the registry), passing the arguments (if any)

The arguments that are passed to each callback is determined by the firing construct. Huh?  The `do_action()` specifies if any arguments will be passed to the callbacks.  Then each callback can declare if it wants them or not.

### Why Can't You Pass the Version?

The `plugins_loaded` event does not pass arguments.  Your callback cannot specify parameters that are not passed from the firing construct.

In other words, the code that does the `do_action’ determines the arguments that your function can choose to accept and use.

Why?  Because the `do_action` is the main firing mechanism.  It says "Hello plugins and themes, I'm running now.  If you are registered to me, then I'll call you tomrun too.  And I might send you some parameters too."

### Options for You

How do you get the version into to your callback?

You have many choices:

- storing it in the database if it's dynamic (will change)
- store it as an environmental variable and load it
- store it as a configuration parameter and load it

As your using OOP, I'd advise injecting it when instantiating the object.  I typically inject the dynamic configuration when I create the objects.

### Reference

Here is a link to the Core code where WordPress fires `do_action( 'plugins_loaded' );`:  [click here to view on GitHub](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-settings.php#L321).  Notice, there are no arguments being declared, which means none will be passed.